# Why is my SqlPackage DeployReport returning an empty report?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to run a DeployReport action with SqlPackage.exe, but it is returning an empty report which I didn't expect since I've dropped several views and SProcs (it shows by running a Compare action in Visual Studio).
According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), DeployReport should

> DeployReport: Creates an XML report of the changes that would be made by a publish action.

I'm using VS2012 against a 2008 R2 SQL server for the database project.
Here's the command:

```
SqlPackage.exe /action:DeployReport /TargetDatabaseName:MyDb /TargetServerName:myServer /TargetUser:user /TargetPassword:password /SourceFile:c:\path\to\project\bin\Debug\project.dacpac
```

Here's the generated report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><DeploymentReport xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dac/DeployReport/2012/02"><Alerts /></DeploymentReport>
```

Comment: Any chance you have the option set somewhere to ignore dropped objects?

Answer (score 4):

Try like this:

```
SqlPackage.exe /action:DeployReport /TargetConnectionString:"{connection string}" /SourceFile:"{dacpac file}" /OutputPath:"{output file}"
```

Comment: I tried this suggestion as well, but getting the same result: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67956360/sqlpackage-deployreport-generate-empty-xml