# sqlpackage DeployReport generate empty xml

Tags: sql-server, xml, sqlpackage

I'm trying to use `sqlpackage.exe` with `DeployReport` action (following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/azure-sqldb?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#deployreport) documentation), but I'm getting empty `xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><DeploymentReport xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dac/DeployReport/2012/02"><Alerts /></DeploymentReport>
```

My command is:

```
sqlpackage /action:DeployReport /SourceFile:"Database Services\bin\Debug\Database Services.dacpac" /TargetServerName:TESTL05,123 /TargetDatabaseName:test /OutputPath:"DeployReport.xml"
```

I tried also to use [this suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23807421/11705021) WA but it didn't help.:

```
SqlPackage.exe /action:DeployReport /TargetConnectionString:"Data Source=TEST05,123;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;Initial catalog=test" /SourceFile:"Database Services\bin\Debug\Database Services.dacpac" /OutputPath:"C:\git\DeployReport.xml"
```

BTW, when I'm doing `publish` action, I do see the expected changes in my DB/
Can you suggest what's wrong here?