# sqlpackage publish action permissions issue

Tags: sql-server, sqlpackage

I'm running the below `sqlpackage` command against my `sqlserver`:

```
 sqlpackage /action:Publish /SourceFile:"Database Services\bin\Release\Database Services.dacpac" /TargetConnectionString:"Data Source=${Env};Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;Initial catalog=${Target}"
```

It contains one `predeploy` script with one alter.
However, I see in the error it tries to `alter` the whole `DB` (one level up) instead just doing the `alter` on the `table`. any idea why? does it related to some flags I need to add as mentioned here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-publish?view=sql-server-ver15#properties-specific-to-the-publish-action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using `/action:Script` (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-script?view=sql-server-ver15)) to see which actions it will perform, most likely this will give you some clue as to which flags should be set/cleared.

-- **Edit**
According to [this old answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42805/how-do-i-turn-off-alter-database-script-output-in-vs-2012) you can disable deploying the database properties when designing the .dacpac.
If you want to override this behaviour when publishing the .dacpac, you should probably use the `ScriptDatabaseOptions` property - see the [whole list of switches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-ver15#properties) here.

Comment: Tnx, you helped me focus on the real issue. Why this part was created and which flag can prevent it: `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM   [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases]
           WHERE  [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')
    BEGIN
        ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
            SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT ON 
            WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    END`

Comment: Tnx a lot! I'm able to understand now from where it came from. can I use your help for another unresolved question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67956360/sqlpackage-deployreport-generate-empty-xml